# Multiple dex files define Lcom/google/android/gms/internal/measurement/zzabn

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, android-studio-3.0, dex

Since this morning I cannot build my Android app because I get this error

> What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithDexMergerForDebug'.
>   com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define
>   Lcom/google/android/gms/internal/measurement/zzabn;

I have tried bumping the Firebase versions accordingly to 15.0.2 but then I get an other error...

> Task :app:processDebugGoogleServices Found com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:15.0.0, but version 15.0.2
>   is needed for the google-services plugin.

com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:15.0.2 is not even released yet?

I have a build to push to production, what is the best way to build the app?

Comment: `"Firebase Android SDKs now have independent version numbers, allowing for more frequent, flexible updates."` See [Multiple dex files define](https://github.com/geektimecoil/react-native-onesignal/issues/20)

Comment: I have updated the version accordingly to 15.0.2 (except -ads which is still 15.0.0) but the build still breaks because the google plugin is looking for google-maps 15.0.2 which is not yet released

Comment: check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50149266/compilation-failed-to-completeprogram-type-already-present-com-google-android/50149536#50149536

Comment: @PeterHaddad bingo updating this classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.3.0' works

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Please update the `google-service` plugin to:

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.3.0'
```

to be able to use the latest version of Firebase and to avoid the errors.

Read the following for more information:

https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2018/05/announcing-new-sdk-versioning.html

[Compilation failed to complete:Program type already present: com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzabn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50149266/compilation-failed-to-completeprogram-type-already-present-com-google-android/50149536#50149536)

Answer (score 0):

*(Posted solution on behalf of the question author)*.

Removing `com.google.gms.google-services` at the bottom of my build.build makes it work.

Comment: this is wrong, please see the comments above, this is the right solution: 


**@PeterHaddad bingo updating this classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.3.0' works**

Comment: This was posted by the question author @Peter, and they said it worked for them.

Comment: yes I know but after that I linked him with the other answer that solved his issue

Comment: Yes the build passed but the Firebase crashed wen the app starts