# Error in Android Studio Multiple dex files define Lcom/google/android/gms/internal/measurement/zzabn;

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I got Error when i run my app

Build Error

> Multiple dex files define Lcom/google/android/gms/internal/measurement/zzabn;

Run Build Error

> org.gradle.initialization.ReportedException: org.gradle.internal.exceptions.LocationAwareException: Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithDexMergerForDebug

Run Task Error

> org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithDexMergerForDebug

Android Issues Error

> Error converting bytecode to dex:
>   Cause: com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lcom/google/android/gms/internal/measurement/zzabn;
>   Message{kind=ERROR, text=Error converting bytecode to dex:
>   Cause: com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lcom/google/android/gms/internal/measurement/zzabn;, sources=[Unknown source file], original message=UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
>   com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lcom/google/android/gms/internal/measurement/zzabn;
>   , tool name=Optional.of(Dex)}
>
> com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lcom/google/android/gms/internal/measurement/zzabn;
>   Message{kind=ERROR, text=com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lcom/google/android/gms/internal/measurement/zzabn;, sources=[Unknown source file]}
>
> at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.readSortableTypes(DexMerger.java:661)
>   Message{kind=ERROR, text=   at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.readSortableTypes(DexMerger.java:661), sources=[Unknown source file]}

build.grandle(Module), build.grandle(Project) Link: https://rewardapp.online/texts.html

Comment: I need help!!!!

Comment: please add your build.gradle to your question.

Comment: I add link to build.grandle(Module), build.grandle(Project) Link: https://rewardapp.online/texts.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multiple dex files define Lcom/google/android/gms/internal/measurement/zzabn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50182756/multiple-dex-files-define-lcom-google-android-gms-internal-measurement-zzabn)

Comment: this duplicate is your answer

Comment: please don't use a link for your question. It's highly discouraged.

Comment: Also check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50149266/compilation-failed-to-completeprogram-type-already-present-com-google-android/50149536#50149536

Comment: ok i put change classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.3.0'  and get ERROR The library com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base is being requested by various other libraries at [[15.0.0,15.0.0], [15.0.2,15.0.2]], but resolves to 15.0.2. Disable the plugin and check your dependencies tree using ./gradlew :app:dependencies.

Comment: Help pls!!!!!!!