# All com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version specification after adding firebase

Tags: android, firebase

My android Studio shows this error.

> All com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version
>   specification (mixing versions can lead to runtime crashes). Found
>   versions 27.1.1, 26.1.0. Examples include
>   com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:27.1.1 and
>   com.android.support:support-media-compat:26.1.0 less... (Ctrl+F1) 
>   There are some combinations of libraries, or tools and libraries, that
>   are incompatible, or can lead to bugs. One such incompatibility is
>   compiling with a version of the Android support libraries that is not
>   the latest version (or in particular, a version lower than your
>   targetSdkVersion).

```
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:15.0.0'
```

Comment: it themes like `com.google.firebase:firebase-core:15.0.0` depends on older support library. There already is `15.0.2` version released. Probably it is based on the latest support library. Meanwhile, you have 2 more options - ignore this message (it is not an error in fact, but a warning), or downgrade your used support libs version to `26.1.0`

Comment: Thanks... I upgraded to firebase 15.0.2 and downgraded api level to 26. 
Now it looks good.

Comment: I'll make it an answer

Comment: You should not downgrade support library version as it is not a solution. Instead you can exclude support group from firebase.

Comment: @parekhkruti26 could you share a link of how to do that, or post an answer? I suffer from this problem same as the question owner, and your solution themes a correct way.

Comment: Sure, just a minute.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [All com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version specification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42374151/all-com-android-support-libraries-must-use-the-exact-same-version-specification)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It themes like `com.google.firebase:firebase-core:15.0.0` depends on older support library varsion (`26.1.0`).
There already is `15.0.2` version released, so you could try to:

- use `15.0.2` version of firebase core. Probably it is based on latest support lib
- ignore this message, as it is a warning, not an error, and probably your app would work fine with it. *(not recommended, but could work)*
- downgrade your used support libs version to `26.1.0` so they are the same version. At least until google releases firebase based on the latest support lib version. *(recommended way if #1 didn't work)*

Comment: Well elaborate!

Answer (score 5):

Instead of downgrading or excluding the support library, you can solve the problem by overriding the support library. You can override the support library by adding the dependency which is in the error:

```
implementation "com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:27.1.1"
```

For argumentation about this answer, you can see the following issues in Firebase:

- [Support Library out of date](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-jobdispatcher-android/issues/81)
- [com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lcom/google/android/gms/auth/api/signin/internal/zzf;](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/issues/414)

Comment: so basically if we directly use latest version of the lib, it will override firebase-dependance version, right?

Comment: That's right. But it's only work for Firebase. Haven't test it with another library.

Comment: It may also cause `:app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug` runtime exception. So it is better to exclude and then add as a safety measure.

Comment: If it causes the above exception then you need to do as specified in the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50182756/multiple-dex-files-define-lcom-google-android-gms-internal-measurement-zzabn

Comment: @parekhkruti26 the problem probably can be solved by PeterHaddad answer. Imho, excluding is doing exactly like overriding but overriding do it beautifully.

Comment: New google-services plugin has some issues when using multi-module, data-binding (others also which I don't know). [Issue tracker link](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/79122163)

Answer (score 1):

When you run `./gradlew :app:dependencies`, you come to know the transitive dependencies of libraries one has included in their gradle.

From that hierarchy view, one can find out which libraries are depending on older versions and `exclude` them in gradle as shown below:

```
 exclude group:'com.android.support'//as an example support library is excluded
```

As far as this question is concerned, it can be done like this:

```
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
implementation ('com.google.firebase:firebase-core:15.0.2'){
    exclude group:'com.android.support'
}
```

Here support library is excluded as firebase core was depending on older versions, creating a conflict.

**NOTE:**

If your dependencies don't include the libraries that you have excluded but the dependency from which you have excluded needs it, you can add the excluded library in gradle with your compatible version.