# Application fail to run on device due to "Multiple dex files define Lcom/google/common/util/concurrent/ListenableFuture"

Tags: android, android-studio, build.gradle, android-workmanager

After adding below dependencies in my project i am getting error : **Multiple dex files define Lcom/google/common/util/concurrent/ListenableFuture;**

```
 def work_version = "1.0.0-beta01"

    implementation "android.arch.work:work-runtime:$work_version" // use -ktx for Kotlin+Coroutines

    // optional - RxJava2 support
    implementation "android.arch.work:work-rxjava2:$work_version"

    // optional - Test helpers
    androidTestImplementation "android.arch.work:work-testing:$work_version"
```

Comment: try this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50182756/multiple-dex-files-define-lcom-google-android-gms-internal-measurement-zzabn)

Answer (score 1):

Try excluding the ListenableFuture module:

```
implementation ("android.arch.work:work-runtime:$work_version") {
    exclude group: 'com.google.guava', module: 'listenablefuture'
}
```